# Why does d.ts files do not throw an error when importing inexistent variables/types?

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

I've got a `d.ts` file that imports an inexistent variable/interface:

```
import { inexistentVariable } from './myFile.ts'
import { InexistentInterface } from './myTypes.d.ts'
```

In both cases, my IDEs (VSCode and WebStorm) do not warn me about this. I can actually make use of it with no warnings given:

```
interface A {
    b: InexistentInterface
}
```

When I hover `b` I get `b: any`.

This is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "target": "ES5",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "lib": [
    "esnext.asynciterable",
    "ES5",
    "ES6",
    "dom"
    ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": ["reflect-metadata", "jest", "jest-chain", "node"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true, 
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,  
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
  },
  "include": [
        "./"
    ],
  "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Is there any way of getting an error when the imported feature does not exist in the codebase?

Comment: Try setting `skipLibCheck` to `false`.

Comment: no luck unfortunatelly

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is intended behavior of Typescript to ensure cooperation with JavaScript.
It was reported on the Typescript Github page here: [Import path not checked when not importing any symbols #20534](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20534) and labeled "working as intended".

The example on github is a little different compared to what you posted, but the underlying reason for the behavior seems to be the same.